# Recognizing numbers from strings in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How could I do it in Node.js to recognize if a string is a valid number?

Here are some examples of what I want:

```
"22"     => true
"- 22"   => true
"-22.23" => true
"22a"    => false
"2a2"    => false
"a22"    => false
"22 asd" => false
```

I dont actually need to return "true" or "false", but I need an unequivocally way to distinguish them. It seems like isNaN isnt available in node.js...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isNaN()` is definitely available in node.js.

`!isNaN(+n)`

The unary plus operator is my personal choice; won't catch your `"- 22"` example, but you could use `!isNaN(+n.replace(/\s/g, "")` to strip spaces.

Comment: You are right. I dont know why it wasnt working before... thanks!

Comment: No problem. It should be noted that javascript thinks `+""` and `+[]` are 0. So this solution doesn't hold up under the very best garbage you throw at it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the method suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/315306):

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: `isNaN` is not available in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp for example :

```
function is_number(n) {
   return (/^-?\d[0-9.e]*$/).test(n);
}
```